# Enable CFR11 Setting in DocuSign Account

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

Kindly help how can I get CFR11 settings enabled in my DocuSign Sand Box or Demo Account?

Answer (score 1):

For developer accounts, DocuSign Customer Service handles that for you:

Remember to include your **developer account ID** with your request to enable a feature on your account.

To have a feature enabled, open a case with customer support. Best practice: use the [Support Portal](https://support.docusign.com/en/login?from=/en/caseOverview?dfl=1) to login with your production (not developer) DocuSign credentials.

Or use the general web form on the [contact support page](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport). Use the DocuSign API Integration Support option at the bottom of the page.

Comment: As an additional note, getting the 21 CFR Part 11 module enabled in Production does require a conversation with Sales. If you already have a point of contact on that side, you can also work with them to get your Sandbox account enabled for 21 CFR Part 11